# Blazor browsing history & page referrer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, navigation, blazor, webassembly

I am facing issue with the navigation in my Blazor application, does blazor NavigationManager have information about the previous pages that user visited. I want to navigate to previous page without page refresh handling it with cancel button event.

Is there a way to get page referrer in blazor.

Could anybody please help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want navigation history within your app, use the navigation manager in the main layout, and keep a list on the navigation event. Then, if you want to move the user with code, the .NavigateTo() method will let you.

If you need history outside of blazor, look into js interop to get at the browser history object.

If you need to know where the user came from to your server through http headers, use the server pipeline itself, I don't think it is exposed on blazor itself